# Generated redundancy in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

While looking through the generated code in Winforms I noticed something that seemed rather pointless:

```
this.aButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), 
                                                       ((int)(((byte)(101)))), 
                                                       ((int)(((byte)(162)))));
```

Color.FromArgb can take int's, so why are those (int) and (byte) casts needed? Why wouldn't VS just generate

```
this.aButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 101, 162)?
```

Comment: Creates a Color structure from the four ARGB component (alpha, red, green, and blue) values. Although this method allows a 32-bit value to be passed for each component, the value of each component is limited to 8 bits. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like some "foolproof" mechanism. Since each color component value should be less than 256 (colors limited to 8 bit), casting this value to `byte` will prevent program from being compiled if developer somehow will enter value greater than 255 as color component.

I.e. this: `(byte)256` will generate compiler error thus indicating to developer problem with color component value.

Comment: After reading the MSDN Narek Arzumanyan linked it still seems pointless to me as the function itself already limits it, Why would you do the same thing twice even if it's small?

Comment: @Gnarly404 Compiler will pass this: `Color.FromArgb(0, 101, 256)` since 256 is pretty valid for `int`. So in this case program will be compiled, but you will get `ArgumentException` when you'll run it. But in the case of `Color.FromArgb(0, 101, (int)((byte)256))` you will get **compilation** error and you will know something wrong with your program even without running it. The earlier you recognize the problem - the better.

Comment: had to test that real quick and you are right. I expected that the values that were higher than 255 were simply limited to 255 and it would still work like usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is an artefact of how the designer serializes property values. The property is serialized using a `TypeConverter` to an `InstanceDescriptor`.

The instance descriptor contains the arguments stored as bytes from the R, G and B properties of the color object, as can be seen using:

```
var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 64);
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(color);

var result = (InstanceDescriptor) converter.ConvertTo(color, typeof(InstanceDescriptor));
var arguments = result.Arguments.Cast<object>().ToList();

Console.WriteLine(arguments[0] is byte);
```

After that the instance descriptor is converted to CodeDom, and then saved as C# code.

The CodeDom just reproduces exactly what its been given, since C# has no native byte type it outputs a cast to a byte. Then the CodeDom sees its calling a method that needs `int`, but it has a `byte` so casts the values to `int`, this is in case an overload that takes a byte exists or is later added.

The CodeDom behaves this way for the simple fact that it doesn't cause any harm and is easy. The part responsible for serializing constant value doesn't need to know or care about how the value is being used. The part responsible for generating the method call doesn't need to know or care where the value is coming from (in this case its a constant, but it could have been a variable, property, method call, etc.) The redundancy will be picked up by the compiler and optimized away.

The ColorConverter could have avoided this by first casting the bytes to ints when generating the arguments for the instance descriptor, but again, what's the point of the extra effort and complexity.